# Disadvantages of using "variable !== FALSE"

Tags: c#, php, coding-style, conditional-statements

Reading a job ad, a requirement (sigh) was that the applicant should more or less hate the usage of `variable !== FALSE`. I, however, cannot see the reason of this, since I find it quite handy.

Say that a function (`get_user( int user_id )`) returns FALSE if it doesn't succeed (find the requested user), I can simply use:

```
user = get_user(823);

if(user !== FALSE) {

   // User found   

} else {

  // No user found

}
```

I could, of course, simply use `if(!user)`, however, I don't always find it suiting, especially when I have a few conditions to meet.

Are there any disadventages of writing code like this?

**Clarification: This is a more global question, as the ad were against PHP usage of `!== FALSE` and C# usage of `!= FALSE`.**

Comment: There are no disadvantages, there are many, many, many advantages. Are you sure you read the requirement correctly?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth This was more ment as pseduo-code of some form, where the operator would be `!=` instead of `!==` in suitable languages. Forgot to mention this.

Comment: @Zar, The difference between `!=` and `!==` is huge in this context.  Which is it?

Comment: How is `if(user != false)` equivalent to `if(!user)`.. Isn't it equivalent to `if(user)`?

Comment: It depends on the language, whether it has type coercion or not. In JavaScript, `if(!user)` or even `if(user !==false)` are very different than `if(user !== false)`. Always use strict comparison, because if you then use loose comparison, it is immediately clear that you explicitly want type coercion. Of course if you know that a variable will always hold a boolean value, comparing it against one is just unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: I think the issue is whether or not to use the `!==` operator. Opinions differ, I think it's hard not to use as it's a fundamental part of JavaScript's loosely typed architecture.

Comment: The ad was against `!= FALSE` and `!== FALSE` in general. No further explaination was left. Most languages have these operators, hence this question is targeted to these.

Comment: @Zar It might help to be more specific about the language in question here. In PHP `!== FALSE` is unavoidable if you want to write code that actually works properly, in javascript this is also true to some degree.

Comment: @DaveRandom I am sure this was the requirement. Couldn't find the reason for this either.

Comment: @DaveRandom The company had the same ad for a PHP-position and a C# position, both stated that the applicant should not use `!= FALSE` (C#) / `!== FALSE` (PHP), which is why I assumed it was a more general question.

Comment: @Zar Beware of using symbols in pseudo-code that are narrow in scope and very specific in meaning. `!==` is very different in meaning and implication to `!=` in the languages it's used in (ECMAScript/JavaScript). It creates a whole lot of assumptions.

Comment: Well requiring that in PHP is just silly, that makes the use of many essential native PHP functions (`strpos()`, `array_shift()` and other stack manipulation functions, `preg_match()` to name three off the top of my head) completely unreliable. Sounds like the job requirements were written by an insufferable purist or an idiot.

Comment: @Zar The problem with that is this question is actually quite language specific. Things like PHP, Perl and to some degree Javascript (basically, loosely typed and/or procedural languages) are basically unusable *without* explicit comparison operators. True OO languages like Java and C# usually use exceptions to indicate errors and return values (even boolean false) are actually return values. Making this more general will result in even less helpful answers than some of the ones you have already received appear to be...

Comment: @DaveRandom I agree. Perhaps it's best to create a new, less global, question?

Comment: @Zar Re-asks don't usually find a warm welcome - you'd be better rewriting this one, you can change everything about it (title, content, tags) at any point.

Comment: You really need to make this *very* specific to a language in order for this to be anywhere near constructive.  Otherwise, it becomes a list of reasons (across languages no less!).

Answer (score 2):

You say get_user returns false when it doesn't succeed - and that's most of the problem. If a function call does not succeed, it should throw an exception, not return an answer that is not type safe ("false" as opposed to a User).

Comment: A very good point, but it doesn't account for the fact that many of PHP's native functions return boolean false when they fail, and may also return values that evaluate to false when coerced to a boolean. You have to work with the way the language was designed. Even if it was designed very badly.

Comment: The answer is subjective (without clearly pointing that out) and especially does not work in context where no such construct of exception exists *or* or is bad practice (e.g. too hard to write good exception handling code, so programmers are not allowed to use that because they screw it).

Comment: I agree with both of you. However, I think this was added as a job requirement more as a style question than literally asking about "!==". If however, this is about the specific Javascript operator, I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

You could do on accident

```
if($variable = FALSE)
```

And this would change the value of `$variable`

Comment: True, but the same is true of `==`/`!=` - a better safeguard against this if `FALSE !== $var`. Or just check your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the two following are equivalents:

```
user != FALSE

!user
```

However, this is slightly different:

```
user !== FALSE
```

as it is the negation of ===, which checks for both values and types to be the same.

Reference:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: `(user != false) !== (!user)` because `true !== false`

Answer (score 0):

If you have in Java

```
Boolean flag1 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean flag2 = new Boolean(false);

if (flag1 == Boolean.TRUE || flag1 == Boolean.FALSE) // is false.
if (flag2 == Boolean.TRUE || flag2 == Boolean.FALSE) // is false.

if (flag1 != Boolean.FALSE && flag2 != Boolean.FALSE) // is true
```

Using == FALSE or != FALSE may not work the way you think so while it is more verbose, it is also error prone.

Answer (score 0):

From a dev point of view, it's better to design your methods that do not return different values that evaluate to FALSE. Eg your function should not return multiple possible values of `0 or NULL or FALSE or "" (empty string) or empty array()` because this would require some unobvious logic to check the result after.

If we talk about PHP on the other hand it's good to know that some functions return both zero or false, eg strpos. You should not assume `if (!strpos(...))` means the string is not contained in the other string, it could be on zero position, which evaluates to `FALSE`. Sometimes also a function might return FALSE on failure or empty array on success (that did not produce result that evaluates to `TRUE`).

So, point out there are cases this is neccessary or useful, but in general its bad practice to return multiple values that evaluate to FALSE, thus requiring to include the type in the comparisment operator.

Answer (score 0):

What is asked for a requirement might be related to taste and to field of use.

In a strict logical system, one might be inclined to select ID values that represent objects (in any kind of store or memory) to not be 0 (and to be positive numbers only).

That leaves room for having 0 to represent a non-existing object (so called NULL object).

Also negative numbers *could* be used to signal meta information like errors. But a strict system should not use any negative numbers and pass meta-information on some context instead of the mainline of data-flow.

Probably this is what is wanted. In that case the value `FALSE` would not exist, because the whole system is about numbers only.

The benefit of such a system is that it works nearly in every programming language and across different paradigms.

Also commonly the number zero expresses a falsy condition, and non-zero numbers a truthy one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the language.

**C**

In the programm language C there is no bool and then TRUE or FALSE are defined values, mostly 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. However, since this is just a sort of convention, some define FALSE as -1 and TRUE as 255. You see this results in strange behavior, therefor in C always check against a defined value and make sure those values match.

Also in C some people think the best way is to use 'FALSE == a' instead of 'a == FALSE'. The reason is that if one = is forgotten, the first (FALSE == a) gives a compilation error, and the second is treated as an assignment, which clearly is unintended.

**C#**

However, in C#, true and false are predefined and checking a variable against true and false is quite useless. a == true means exactly the same as  just writing a.

**Python**

In Python however, there is a change. a == true means that the variable a should be a boolean, if you write just 'a' then it means it can also be 0, [], {} or any inited value.

A bit off-topic: I think if such detail is part of a 'requirement for a job', the job requirements would be like 10,000 pages.